# Is there a way to send "User is typing..." status in telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I wanted to send an update to an entity that will show up as "X is typing..." (X being me) on their (recipient's) side. I've looked through the docs (especially under the [`telethon.client`](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telethon.client.html) package) and couldn't find a method that does that. Is it possible to send such an update using telethon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `SetTypingRequest`. Read more about it here:

https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/methods/messages/set_typing.html

Example:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.messages.SetTypingRequest(
        peer='username',
        action=types.SendMessageTypingAction()
    ))
    print(result)
```

Don't forget to cancel the typing action after some time; you probably don't want to type forever :-D

https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/constructors/send_message_cancel_action.html

Comment: Thanks! The typing status usually clears after 5 seconds, but also stops after using `send_message` to send a message.